# UITableViewCell Does not respond to the responder chain

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I encountered a problem during the development, I have a `UITableViewCell`, it adds a `UIButton` (`UIButton` was full of the Cell), I hope my `UIButton` response my `touchupinside` event, after processing is completed, the events send up again, until the Cell to response `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method.but now,`didSelectRowAtIndexPath` didn't work? (note: I don't want to manually call `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method, I hope that through the responder chain to solve this problem)

Comment: button action is working but did selectrow is not being called right?

Answer (score 1):

If the button is smaller than the cell, it should work as expected: if you touch the button, the button handler fires, if you touch another area in the cell, `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` fires.

If, however, the button covers the entire cell, this is a non-issue. You can call the same routine from the button handler as from the table view delegate.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
    didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   [self doCellThingWithIndexPath:indexPath];
}

- (void)buttonAction:(UIButton*)sender {
    // do whatever the button does, then
    CGRect buttonFrame = [button convertRect:sender.bounds toView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView 
                              indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonFrame.origin];
    [self doCellThingWithIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```